# Changing print-layout/print-template with ArcGIS Maps SDK for JavaScript

Tags: arcgis-online, printing

we got "the first step" print with ArcGIS Maps SDK 4.27 for JavaScript succesfully. But I wonder:

a) Is it possible to change the scalebar, that the units are only shown in kilometers (not in miles)?

b) Is it possible to put an own image (logo) into the printout?

c) Is it possible to set a text in the printout, that has some "breaks" (like html-
 or \n)?

It might be that we have to create complete own and new templates. Could anybody give some hints, how this can be done?

This is the code so far:

```
const print = new Print({
  view: view,
  printServiceUrl:
     "https://utility.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Utilities/PrintingTools/GPServer/Export%20Web%20Map%20Task",
       allowedLayouts: ["a3-landscape", "a3-portrait","a4-landscape", "a4-portrait" ],
         allowedFormats: ["jpg", "png8", "png32","pdf"],
templateOptions: {
  title: "Datenausdruck",
  author: "Part 1, Part 2, Part 3",
  copyright: "",
  legendEnabled: false

}
});


view.ui.add(print, {
  position: "top-right"
});
```